# Use of undeclared identifiers in Destination file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Am getting flagged by the compiler for having undeclared identifiers, and wonder what is the best way to fix this issue?

This is the first time I'm using a plist to store data, so I'm not sure what the best approach is. Thank you.

Have commented out the error messages:

Destination.h

```
#import "Destination.h"

@implementation Destination

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;
@synthesize destinationName = _destinationName;
@synthesize destinationImage = _destinationImage;

-(id)initWithDestinationIndex:(NSUInteger)destinationIndex {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Destinations" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *destinations = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSArray *destinationsArray = [destinations objectForKey:@"DestinationData"];
    NSDictionary *data = [destinationsArray objectAtIndex:destinationIndex];

    self.destinationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[data objectForKey:@"DestinationImage"]];
    self.destinationName = [data objectForKey:@"DestinationName"];
    NSDictionary* destinationLocation = [data objectForKey:@"DestinationLocation"];
    destinationCoordinate.latitude = [[destinationLocation objectForKey:@"Latitude"]doubleValue];// Use of undeclared identifier 'destinationCoordinate'
    destinationCoordinate.longitude = [[destinationLocation objectForKey:@"Longitude"]doubleValue];// Use of undeclared identifier 'destinationCoordinate'
    self.coordinate = destinationCoordinate;//Use of undeclared identifier 'destinationCoordinate'
    self.title = [destinationLocation objectForKey:@"Title"];
    self.subtitle = [destinationLocation objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];
  }
  return self;
}

-(UIImage *)destinationImage {
  return destination.destinationImage;//Use of undeclared identifier 'destination'; did you mean 'Destination'?
}

-(NSString *)destinationName {
  return  destinationName;//Use of undeclared identifer 'destinationName'; did you mean '_destinationName'?
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destinationCoordinate {
  return destination.coordinate;//Use of undeclared 'destination'; did you mean 'Destination'
}

@end
```

Destination.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Destination : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic,readwrite)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite,copy)NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite,copy)NSString *subtitle;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *destinationName;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *destinationImage;
-(id)initWithDestinationIndex:(NSUInteger)destinationIndex;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `destinationImage` method altogether.  You have already synthesized it and it should work fine, as is.

Comment: Thank you. Have done that, but am stilling getting same errors for other variables (destinationCoordinate and others). Should they be declared as local variables?

Comment: @pdenlinger Well if they are same problem, then the same solution will work I guess.